# Как приравнять компонент из переменной Unity

Tags: unity3d

```cs
empty.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
empty.GetComponent<MeshFilter>() = Data_Map.worldObjects[i].meshFilter;
```

Как можно приравнять компонент переменной?
Этот кусок кода выдаёт ошибку, так как левая часть не является переменной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, это нарушение идеологии компонентов в Unity. Компоненты нельзя создавать вручную. Единственный способ создать объект компонента - `AddComponent<T>()`. После этого, как с точки зрения кода, так и с точки идеологии, компонент намертво прикреплен к объекту. Его можно настроить или удалить, но никак нельзя поменять на другой. И нет, компонент не может существовать без родительского объекта.

Особенно учитывая, что компоненты априори нельзя создать в отрыве от объекта, как вы вообще смогли сформировать массив `Data_Map.worldObjects`.

---

Судя по контексту, вы хотите переключать полигональную сетку при каких-то условиях. Проще хранить массив мешей и менять их у фильтров:

`empty.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = Data_Map.worldMeshes[i]`